# How to change Business Unit while migrating MSCRM data from 4.0 to higher version using Scribe Workbench?

Tags: dynamics-crm, data-migration, scribe-workbench

I want to migrate CRM 4.0 data to new MSCRM 2013 organization. While I connect the source(CRM 4.0) to destiny (CRM 5.0) and do AutoLink to run the job, I get the error "Business unit with ID ... not found". That is valid error message.

However, I am not able to change the business unit of source. I tried hardcoding the business unit ID in Source field (Business Unit) but still the job fails. When I hardcode the business unit ID in formula editor, I get error "Guid should have 32 characters with four dashes". The guid I provided is in correct format and I still get this error.

Let me know where I am going wrong and how can we migrate data from one CRM org to another CRM org using Scribe without having business unit ID not found errors.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what entity type is causing the error. I'm presuming it's the SystemUser entity. Please advise if not.

The guid of the business unit in the source (CRM4) won't be the same as the guid of the BU in the target (CRM 2013).

Be careful with Autolink in Scribe as it may link fields that you didn't intend to link. I always link manually.

I think that CRM will generate the error you report in this case if the guid doesn't match to a BU (even if it's a valid guid).

Also note that Scribe can't be used to change the business unit of a user, however it will allow the BU to be specified when the user is created.

Mike